# MessageBox in code c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, messagebox

how to add a messagebox 
"Item Not Found" of this code? 
Thanks!

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "Search")
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView_produkty.Rows)
            {
                if (dgvr.Cells[0].Value != null)
                {
                    if (dgvr.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox_szukaj.Text))
                    {
                        dgvr.Visible = true;
                        continue;                                             
                    }
                    dgvr.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which part of the code actually implies that the item was not found? after which condition / loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx) class and use it's [`Show`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598674(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
MessageBox.Show("Item not found");
```

Use a flag with it and you will be good to go.

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "Search")
{
    bool itemFound = false;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView_produkty.Rows)
    {
        if (dgvr.Cells[0].Value != null)
        {
            if (dgvr.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox_szukaj.Text))
            {
                dgvr.Visible = true;
                itemFound = true;
                continue;                                             
            }
            dgvr.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    if (!itemFound)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Item not found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "Search")
{
    var itemFound = false;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView_produkty.Rows)
    {
        if (dgvr.Cells[0].Value != null)
        {
            if (dgvr.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox_szukaj.Text))
            {
                dgvr.Visible = true;
                itemFound = true;
                continue;                                             
            }
            dgvr.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    if (!itemFound)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Item not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: this will show Item not found for every row not matching the search criteria. Not what expected, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows the messagebox if `textBox_szukaj.Text` don't contain in any row.

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "Search")
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView_produkty.Rows)
    {
        if (dgvr.Cells[0].Value != null)
        {
            if (dgvr.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox_szukaj.Text))
            {
                dgvr.Visible = true;
                found = true;
                continue;                                             
            }
            dgvr.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    if(!found) MessageBox.Show("Item not found");
}
```